# value from 'HTML' form to 'PHP' file is not going to php file

Tags: php, html

My task is i want to create form for search field. want to transfer the value from search to required php file which is 'result.php'. But I am getting bug that I am  unable to solve this. please anyone help me. I am new to php..

**HTML CODING :**

```
 <form action="result.php" method="POST">
    <input type="search" name="query" size="10" id="searchfield" title="searchfield" />
    <input type="submit" name="Search" value="" alt="Search" id="searchbutton" title="Search" />
    </form>
```

**PHP CODE :**

```
//result.php

@session_start();
include 'connections.php';
//echo "hai"; // I debug this code with the help of echo statements. and  successfully printing hai

if (isset($_POST['query']) && $_POST['query'] != ""){// unable to enter in `if` condition 
$query = $_POST['query'];
$min_length = 1;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
{
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
............`
```

value that entered in search field is not going from 'HTML' form to 'PHP' file to perform required operations please anyone help me to solve this bug..

Comment: Are your both files in same directory ?

Comment: In your comments where you are echo'ing out the $query, you are assigning incorrectly, you have $query = var_dump($_POST['$query']); but further down you assign it correctly using $query = $_POST['query'];

Comment: with the help of var_dump() i am just checking what value is I am getting... and its just debugging.. I did debugging by echoing the simple statements

Comment: you might want to change how your using mysql - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: to check the value, just do : $query = $_POST['query']; echo $query;

Comment: yes both files are in same directory. @Vin000

Comment: with the help of $_POST['query'], I am not getting value. that is the major problem I am facing. I don't know what mistake I did @Endacy

Answer (score 1):

If the values is printed with `var_dump($_POST['query']);`then it's actually sent by form. And why are you testing twice for lenght of it. Try testing if value is set in file where you got form. Test it with jquery. Then in result.php just check if value is posted. And what are you trying to do with value in result.php?

Try

```
var_dump($_POST['query']);
if (isset($_POST['query'])){// unable to enter in `if` condition due to NULL value.
$query = $_POST['query'];
$min_length = 1;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
{
$query = htmlspecialchars($query);
$query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
}
}else
{
echo 'novalues';
}
```

**EDIT**

You can try sending value with ajax. Add below code in script tag in your file with form and thats it.

```
    $("#searchbutton").click(function(){ 
    var value = $("#searchbutton").val(); 
    $.ajax({
    url: "result.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: value, 
    success: function(result){
     $("#div1").html(result); 
    }
    }); 
   });
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['$query']);` in your explaination, lose the $ for query ;)

Comment: we are developing simple library website. we have books in our database. developing search operation.. for that...

Comment: not worked... same as before I am getting NULL with     var_dump($_POST['$query']);

Comment: Hmm. Try removing @ before session, so you will see if any errors there. Then try putting type of input to text instead of search (html5).

Comment: I am sorry to say, It doesn't work for me @NejcRodošek

Comment: then last thing you can do is to post value of input  with ajax.

Comment: will you please help me with ajax. I am completely unaware with ajax.. give me just example snippet..@NejcRodošek

Answer (score 1):

Try to change type of your input like this

```
<input type="text" name="query" size="10" id="searchfield" title="searchfield" />
```

just to be sure it doesn't cause your problem :)

Comment: No use... @Branimir Durek

Comment: well your code looks fine... press f12 and open network tab. Then submit your form and check your request POST data to be sure that your form sends "query" value. If it works, then try to comment everything and then echo $_POST["query"] just to be sure that rest of your code doesn't cause the problem...

Comment: nothing worked for me. I don not know why.. even I checked with ajax and javascript. value from 'html' form to php file is not getting.......

Comment: are you sure you don't have duplicated project?? So you edit one, but you test functionality on other...

Answer (score 0):

finally I resolved my problem.. problem occurred due to "access permissions" I rewrite the access permissions.. now it is working thank to everyone